# apache vhost not working consistently

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, virtualhost, netcat

I have a vhost on my webserver whose sole and unique goal is to return the client IP adress:

```
petrus@bzn:~$ cat /home/vhosts/domain.org/index.php
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; echo "\n" ?>
```

This helps me troubleshoot networking issues, especially when NAT is involved. As such, I don't always have domain name resolution and this service needs to work even if queried by its IP address.

**I'm using it this way:**

```
petrus@hive:~$ echo "GET /" | nc 88.191.133.41 80
191.51.4.55

petrus@hive:~$ echo "GET /" | nc ydct.org 80
191.51.4.55

router#more http://88.191.133.41/index.php
88.191.124.254
```

**However I found that it wasn't working from at least a computer:**

```
petrus@seth:~$ echo "GET /" | nc ydct.org 80
petrus@seth:~$

petrus@seth:~$ echo "GET /" | nc 88.191.133.41 80
petrus@seth:~$
```

**What I checked:**

This is not related to ipv6:

```
petrus@seth:~$ echo "GET /" | nc -4 ydct.org 80
petrus@seth:~$ 

petrus@hive:~$ echo "GET /" | nc ydct.org 80
2a01:e35:ee8c:180:21c:77ff:fe30:9e36
```

`netcat` version is the same (except platform, i386 vs x64):

```
petrus@seth:~$ type nc
nc est haché (/bin/nc)
petrus@seth:~$ file /bin/nc
/bin/nc: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/nc'
petrus@seth:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/nc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 2010-06-26 14:01 /etc/alternatives/nc -> /bin/nc.openbsd

petrus@hive:~$ type nc
nc est haché (/bin/nc)
petrus@hive:~$ file /bin/nc
/bin/nc: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/nc'
petrus@hive:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/nc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 2011-05-26 01:23 /etc/alternatives/nc -> /bin/nc.openbsd
```

It works when used without the pipe:

```
petrus@seth:~$ nc ydct.org 80
GET /
2a01:e35:ee8c:180:221:85ff:fe96:e485
```

And the piping works at least with a test service (`netcat` listening on 1234/tcp and output to stdout)

```
petrus@bzn:~$ nc -l -p 1234
GET /
petrus@bzn:~$

petrus@seth:~$ echo "GET /" | nc ydct.org 1234
petrus@seth:~$
```

I don't know if this issue is more related to `netcat` or `Apache`, but I'd appreciate any pointers to troubleshoot this issue !

> `bzn` is the server, `hive` is a working client and `seth` is the
>   client on which I have the issue.

Edit:
It works also with `telnet` but `telnet` doesn't allow piping.

**2nd edit in answer to MickeyB:**

Indeed host headers are not transmitted, but as seen with `hive` host above, I've configured the `default` vhost of Apache to behave like `ydct.org` vhost:

```
petrus@bzn:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cat default
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName 88.191.133.41
        ServerAlias 2a01:e1b:1:132:1a0a:a9ff:fec8:f0a9
        DocumentRoot /home/vhosts/ydct.org/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, it works with `curl`!

```
petrus@seth:~$ curl ydct.org
2a01:e35:ee8c:180:221:85ff:fe96:e485
```

Output of `apache2 -S` posted to http://pastebin.com/aSf446Jv

But I'd like to know why it doesn't work with `netcat`...

Comment: What happens if you use `telnet` instead of `netcat`?

Comment: @quanta: telnet client doesn't seem to allow piping...

Comment: `telnet 88.191.124.41 80` and `GET /` followed by Enter.

Comment: @quanta: oh, this works. As netcat btw (see "It works without the pipe").

Comment: You're not actually hitting the vhost - see my answer.

Comment: Post the output of `httpd -S` (or `apache2 -S`)

Comment: @MikeyB: ouput : http://pastebin.com/aSf446Jv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, its the version of netcat you are running.

I tested the command string on my machines as follows:

Mac OS X Lion:

```
yvaine:sqlite user$ echo -e "GET /" | nc 88.191.133.41 80
XX.XX.XX.168
```

FreeBSD:

```
[root@freebsd82 /usr/ports]# echo -e "GET /" | nc 88.191.133.41 80
XX.XX.XX.168
```

CentOS:

```
[root@kvm0001 ~]# echo -e "GET /" | nc 88.191.133.41 80
XX.XX.XX.168
```

Debian (version 6)

```
root@debian:~# echo -e "GET /" | nc 88.191.133.41 80
XX.XX.XX.168
```

Its not until I got to Ubuntu "lucid" (which is what you are apparently are running) is when I got this:

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo -e "GET /" | nc 88.191.133.41 80
root@ubuntu:~#
```

It appears that Ubuntu defaults to nc.openbsd rather that nc.traditional (which is the default on Debian). Once I use the traditional version, I received the desired output:

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo -e "GET /" | nc.traditional 88.191.133.41 80
XX.XX.XX.168
```

What is curious that both of your client machines have nc.openbsd, yet they different in behavior. Of course, it could be that one of them either has a different version of nc.openbsd or a different version of Ubuntu altogether. In either that, you can sync your versions of nc.openbsd or switch over to nc.traditional.

Comment: Yes! You found it: it works with `nc.traditional` on Ubuntu 10.10, on `seth`. However, it's working on 11.04 with `nc.openbsd` on `hive`...

Answer (score 1):

Works for me :)

```
michael@challenger:~$ echo -e "GET /\n" | nc 88.191.124.41 80
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
```

If you are trying to hit the vhost you are doing so incorrectly. You need to send a Host: header to identify the virtual host which you want to use.

The best way of using your 'what is my IP' service would be curl. Hey look, I see the same problem on my end when I do what you're doing:

```
michael@challenger:~$ echo -e "GET /" | nc ip.mydomain.ca 80
michael@challenger:~$ curl ip.mydomain.ca
192.168.0.135
```

---

**FIX YOUR VHOSTS!!!**

```
michael@challenger:~$ curl -v 88.191.124.41
* About to connect() to 88.191.124.41 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 88.191.124.41... connected
* Connected to 88.191.124.41 (88.191.124.41) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: 88.191.124.41
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2011 22:11:31 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
< Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Aug 2010 08:11:38 GMT
< ETag: "840d09-b1-48ea16e57f5a6"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 177
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-Pad: avoid browser bug
< 
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host 88.191.124.41 left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Mmh, it works with `curl`. But it should work without host headers. See my edit.

Comment: You don't have vhosts set up correctly. That's part of the problem.

Comment: Examining the output of 'httpd -S' should help identify why things aren't going to work as you expect in all cases. You need to fix your vhosts.

Comment: MikeyB is right. Apache must be able to know from the client where to redirect to the right virtualhost - hence, the host header request. Otherwise, the server will go to the default DocumentRoot.

Comment: @Rilindo: default DocumentRoot is `/home/vhosts/domain.org`. default and `domain.org` vhost use the same file. Moreover, it works without the host header on `hive`...

Comment: is http://88.191.124.41/ a valid address? Getting to http://88.191.124.41/index.php returns a 404 message.

Comment: MikeyB, @Rilindo: I see where is my mistake. As said above, 88.191.124.41 is not my IP, I "anonimized" it, without checking if it was answering. I should have used a RFC1918 address...

Comment: MikeyB, @Rilindo, I edited my answer to set the real domain, `ydct.org`. It resolves to `88.191.133.41`.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you put the dump of your httpd.conf file in either pastebin or in a gist.

Comment: @Rilindo: output of `apache2 -S` posted to http://pastebin.com/aSf446Jv

Comment: See my response below. Looks like the issue is client side.

Answer (score 0):

Set a wait time and try again:

```
$ echo "GET /" | nc -w 3 88.191.124.41 80
```

Comment: good idea, but no change. Still doesn't work